# Php Export Array to CSV in Windows CMD?

Tags: php

is there a way to export an array into csv file via running the php script in Window's command prompt (cmd)?

To run the php script in cmd I use: C:\php\php.exe -f "C:\filename.php"

Thanks in advance.

Update:
I have tried the following, which doesn't seem to work in a cmd setting.

```
function array_to_csv_download($OutputArray, $filename = "export.csv", $delimiter=";") {
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w'); 
    foreach ($OutputArray as $line) { 
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter); 
    }
    fseek($f, 0);
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');
    fpassthru($f);
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? show us your best attempt(code). please read [ask]

Comment: I have tried the following, which doesn't seem to work in a cmd setting. 

'function array_to_csv_download($OutputArray, $filename = "export.csv", $delimiter=";") {
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w'); 
    foreach ($OutputArray as $line) { 
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter); 
    }
    fseek($f, 0);
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');
    fpassthru($f);
}'

Comment: Sorry to ask a dumb question, but you are calling the function in your script? Just making sure.

Comment: Yes, I have called the function, result is printing on the screen in cmd but no csv file in root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
// file script.php

function array_to_csv_download($OutputArray, $filename = "export.csv", $delimiter=";") {
    $lines= [];
    foreach ($OutputArray as $row) {
        $lines[]= implode($row, $delimiter);
    }
    $fileContent = implode($lines, "\n");
    file_put_contents($filename, $fileContent);
}

$arrayToExport = [
    ["something", "to", "export"],
    ["something", "to", "export2"],
    ["something", "to", "export3"],
];

array_to_csv_download($arrayToExport);
```

That function would create the file if not exists with the content inside. You don't need to download it. Enter the script.php directory and execute `php script.php`;

Comment: Tried and no luck.

Comment: Hi Lucas, tried no luck. I think it must be due to permission setting on my Windows 10 desktop. Unlike on a hosted server I can set the chomd, I am uncertain as to how to get the file full write permission in Windows to create the csv file. I checked folder and user rights, both read/write and admin level respectively.

Comment: @David try opening the cmd console with admin rights before executing the script. Also check that the output file is not being generated in upper level folders such as C:/.